# Perl CGI Output Buffering Using XAMPP Apache Server

Tags: apache, perl, xampp, output-buffering

I recently picked up a CGI Programming with Perl book and while trying to test one of the example problems I ran into an issue.  According to the book newer versions of Apache (since v1.3) do not buffer the output of CGI scripts by default, but when I run the script below, it waits until the entire loop completes before it prints anything:

```
# count.cgi

#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe" -wT

use strict;

#print "$ENV{SERVER_PROTOCOL} 200 OK\n";
#print "Server: $ENV{SERVER_SOFTWARE}\n";
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

print "OK, starting time consuming process ... \n";

# Tell Perl not to buffer our output
$| = 1;

for ( my $loop = 1; $loop <= 30; $loop++ ) {
    print "Iteration: $loop\n";
    ## Perform some time consuming task here ##
    sleep 1;
}

print "All Done!\n";
```

The book said that using an older version of Apache you may need to run the script as an "nph" script so the output would not be buffered, but I even tried that with no luck.

```
# nph-count.cgi

#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe" -wT

use strict;

print "$ENV{SERVER_PROTOCOL} 200 OK\n";
print "Server: $ENV{SERVER_SOFTWARE}\n";
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

print "OK, starting time consuming process ... \n";

# Tell Perl not to buffer our output
$| = 1;

for ( my $loop = 1; $loop <= 30; $loop++ ) {
    print "Iteration: $loop\n";
    ## Perform some time consuming task here ##
    sleep 1;
}

print "All Done!\n";
```

I am running: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15

Clearly this version of Apache is beyond v1.3 so what is going on here? I did a little research and found that if you have "mod_deflate" or "mod_gzip" enabled it can cause output to be buffered, but I checked my configuration files and "mod_deflate" and "mod_gzip" are already both disabled.  All of the other posts I have seen about buffering refer to PHP and say to modify "php.ini", but I am using Perl, not PHP, so that doesn't seem to be the solution.

Also I don't know if this helps at all but I am using Chrome as my web browser.

How can I stop Apache from buffering my output? Thanks!

Comment: Include the charset: `print "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n\n";`

Comment: @kums: Just tried it, no luck. It still takes the full 30 seconds before it displays anything.

Comment: Have you tried this with other browsers? Do they show the same behaviour?

Comment: @kums: It reacts the same on Internet Explorer. Not sure about Firefox, I can try installing it but I don't think the issue is browser related.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling 'mod_deflate'.

Simply move/delete it from your mods-enabled directory.
Don't forget to restart apache after doing so.

Comment: I can try moving it, but the line to include mod_deflate in the configuration file is already commented out so I doubt moving it will change anything.

Comment: I moved the mod_deflate module with no luck, the output is still buffered, got any other ideas?